# Testing an n-tier web application - should my test project have its own database?

Tags: testing

In an n-tier web-app, should I be running integration tests against a different database, one dedicated to testing the code?  Is it standard practice to test against the production database as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never run untested code on production. After all, you don't want to discover that it has a bug that wipes out all data. That's what tests are supposed to find. And you should not have test/staging data in the production system.  It is good practice to dump the data out of production and load it into another environment for periodic testing with real-world data.

You should have a test database (not shared with production). It's a good idea to wipe out the data before every test.

You can have smoke tests that run in production. They will pretend to be a user(agent) and visit many pages, maybe even create things (with a special tag so you can find them again and delete them.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather think of different database user with own data set. Database schema should be the same. I'd never run tests on production database with the same database user. Test logic shouldn't even be delivered to the client as it may lead to severe security issues.

In my opinion you'd need a full production-like data set for testing purposes, to be able to test every single feature of your application. And also you would need an empty database (without any bussiness data) for application clients to have it as initial point on delivery. Such a dataset shouldn't be tested as there is no data needed to test bussiness logic.